# angularJS $http CORS call handshake fails with TLS 1.2 bi directional in IE11

Tags: angularjs, ssl, tls1.2

i created a hello world using angularJS 1.7 and running the webpage using http-server node module.
In the controller using $http service a CORS call is made.

CORS call is trying to establish a TLS 1.2 mutual authentication with an API. Certificates on both the server and the client are installed.  When tested with Chrome initial handshake fails, but it gives a popup to select the certificate. once the certificate is selected the handshake is successful and data is retrieved.

Certificates are self signed added at root level.

However the same fails in IE11.
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is set to the client's IP.

below are wire shark logs.
Client send Hello
Server respond with Server hello and certificates.

However the server sends an alert to "Close Notify"

[Wire shark handshake logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZG4s.png)

[rest error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdIoi.png)

The flag in the response say "Reset"

Below is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<p>Response log:</p>
<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>
<p> Status </p>
<h3> {{pstatus}} </h3>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: 'https://serveraddress:portno/myrestapi/methodcall/',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  }).catch(function(error){
    $scope.myWelcome= error;
});
```

i havent found a similar article

[IE is not sending Client certificate in TLS mutual authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859942/ie-is-not-sending-client-certificate-in-tls-mutual-authentication)

however it didnt resolve the problem.

Any suggestion why the handshake is getting closed? any input?
Doew IE11 support this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you see in chrome network tab?

Comment: There is no error in the chrome however it shows a popup to select the certificate.once the certificate is selected it will call is successful.